# How to check Date with Joda-time to Save and sort data day by day?

Tags: java, android, time, jodatime

I'm setting up an app to save my moods. 
My code look like that

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE, dd").withLocale(Locale.FRANCE);
        day = fmt.print(dt);
```

It's perfect to get the date, but now I would like to check when the date change, to not overwrite my last mood.
I would like to save my moods, day by day.

I'm using SharedPreferences to save my moods and my code look like that:

```
private void saveDateTime(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        DateTime dt = new DateTime();
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE, dd").withLocale(Locale.FRANCE);
        day = fmt.print(dt);
        editor.putString(DATE, day);
        editor.apply();
        editor.commit();
    }
```

If SomeOne have an idea to help me, do not hesitate ;)

Comment: Shouldn’t you use `LocalDate` if you’re not interested in the time of day?

Comment: I'm just interested in the date of the day, yes. But I don't know how to check when the date change, and how to make new key after midnight.

Comment: I’m not an Android developer, so I don’t know either. A different point, for new code you may prefer java.time, the modern Java date and time API, over Joda-Time. If not yet on API level 26, use the backport, [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).